# How to plot a csv file containing txt files (with dataset) on Python

Tags: python, csv

I had 12 text files (txt) corresponding to the 12 months of the year. Each text file has around 70 to 90 data inside.
I have tried querying them on Excel to obtain a csv file, so it means that I have different queries and not a whole spreadsheet with all the data (that means that I can switch back and forth to one query "January" to another "february")
Can I plot this on Python (Jupyter Notebook) to obtain a graph that displays the number of incidents for each month?
I am very new to Python and I have tried researching but my csv file is not a whole spreadsheet, it's divided in queries.

Comment: A csv file is a text files containing data as comma separated value. It is not a spreadsheet and has no notion of queries

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy, I meant that I wanted to combine all the text file to obtain an excel file in order to plot on python...